# apply fuzzy matching logic between rows in same dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, duplicates, fuzzy

I am trying to apply fuzzy logic between multiple rows in a same dataframe.
I want to apply deduplication logic for nearly matching rows in a same dataframe.

ex- drop duplicates wont work for rahul & rahul m.

```
   ID   name     salary
0   1   Rahul    7000
2   3   sarthak  5000
3   1   Rahul m  7000
4   5   priyansh 2500
5   6   Aman     3500
6   1   Rahul    7000
```

I can see code for fuzzy logic between columns in two dataframes but not for rows in same dataframe?

Comment: Can you simply transpose the dataframe (`df.T`) and apply the column-based code?

Comment: can you `split()` the names by whitespace and then drop the duplicates using first names?